# Вызов callback функции из C++ (V8)

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

Здравствуйте. Использую V8 для реализации скриптования в программе. Имеется такая функция на JS:

```
__loadSubScene(name, pathToSceneDescriptor, loadPhysics, (err) => {
    alert('Scene was loaded!');
});
```

а также обработчик на C++:

```
void APIFunctions::__loadSubScene(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& 
args)
{
    if (args.Length() == 4) {
        v8::String::Utf8Value v8SceneName(args[0]);
        std::string name = ConvertUtils::toString(*v8SceneName);

        v8::String::Utf8Value v8Path(args[1]);
        std::string path = ConvertUtils::toString(*v8Path);

        v8::Local<v8::Boolean> isLoadPhysics = args[2]->ToBoolean();

        v8::Handle<v8::Function> callback = 
            v8::Handle<v8::Function>::Cast(args[3]);

        TLMFacade::getInstance().loadSubScene(ConvertUtils::toWstring(name), 
            ConvertUtils::toWstring(path), isLoadPhysics->BooleanValue(), [=](void* _result) {
            // функция должна быть вызвана здесь
        });
    }
}
```

При вызове callback из C++ получаю ошибку. Возможно кому-то известны правила, по которым следует выполнять такие действия или пример. Спасибо.

Comment: Какую ошибку ? Покажите текст ошибки.

Comment: JS хорошо ест IDispath. Создать ScriptControl, и туда можно добавить обьектов IDispath и скрипт.

Comment: #
# Fatal error in d:\projects\v8-nuget\v8\src\api.h, line 349
# Check failed: that == 0 || (*reinterpret_cast<v8::internal::Object* const*>(that))->IsJSReceiver().
#